# How to find a row in a dataframe where some specific values are present and values are not dependent on columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq2Rw.png)

How to find the row in the above dataframe in which Rahul, Sen and rahul.sen@xyz.com, present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `dataframe`:

```
  Table Name                  X        Y        Z        W
0  OfferInfo              Rahul  corolla  corolla  corolla
1  OfferInfo             Aakash      sen  corolla  corolla
2  OfferInfo             Somesh   nissan  corolla  corolla
3  OfferInfo  rahul.sen@xyz.com    Rahul  corolla      Sen
```

You can iterate over each row and check *any* row contains your search list.

```py
# Order does not matter, we check if there is any entry
# that contains these values in their columns.
row_seach = ['Rahul', 'Sen', 'rahul.sen@xyz.com']

# If we will not find it, its value will stay -1.
search_index = -1

# Iterate over dataframe.
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # If all search items can be found within current row, then we found it.
    if all(elem in df.iloc[index, :].values.tolist() for elem in row_seach):
        search_index = index
        break

print(search_index)  # 3

print(df.iloc[3])  # Row 3 contains search items indeed.
```